# How to prove that $ \int_0^{\infty}\frac{-1+e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x^3}}dx$ absolutely converges?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to prove that the following integral is absolutely converges by the comparenes or the limit tests:
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{-1+e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x^3}}dx
$$
From this [topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863694/convergence-of-an-improper-integral-int-0-infty-frac-1-e-x-sqrt-x3d) I know that it converges but how to prove that it absolutely converges?

Comment: Where does the integrand change sign?

Comment: Function under integral is negative.

Comment: The function is completely negative in $\;(0,\infty)\;$, so if you already know it converges then you already know it converges absolutely...

Answer (score 0):

Since $|e^{-x}-1|\leq 2$ for all non-negative $x$, the integral converges absolutely away from zero by comparison to $x^{-3/2}$. Near zero, the Taylor expansion of $e^{-x}$ gives
$$-1+e^{-x}\sim -x+o(x^2)$$ so that
$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{|-1+e^{-x}|}{x^{3/2}}\cdot\sqrt{x}=1$$
which shows that the integral converges absolutely in a right nbd of zero too, by comparison to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(x)=\frac{e^{-x}-1}{\sqrt{x^3}}$$

$ f$ is continuous at $ (0 +\infty)$, so it is locally integrable at $ (0,+\infty).$

$ f$ has a constant sign $(-)$, therefore

we can use limit-comparison test.

At first, notice that $$|f(x)|=\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x\sqrt{x}}$$

Near $0$, we have

$$|f(x)|\sim \frac{x}{x\sqrt{x}}\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$
with $$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}\; convergent$$

Near $+\infty$, we have

$$|f(x)|\sim \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}\sim \frac{1}{x^{\frac 32}}$$
with
$$\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{\frac 32}}\; convergent$$
The integral $ \int_0^{+\infty}f \; is\;  Absolutely\;  convergent$.